# send JSON array from Express to Angular2

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, express, angular

I am trying to send a self-made array that contains the errors from mongoose, and it makes the array fine.
Here is the code:

```
student.save(function(err, student) {
    if(err)
        var errors = [];
        for (field in err.errors) {
            errors.push({error: err.errors[field].message})
        };
        res.contentType('application/json').status(500).send(JSON.stringify(errors));
    res.status(200).json(student);
});
```

It will create an array as such:

```
[ { error: 'Error, expected `_id` to be unique. Value: `111111` },
{ error: 'Error, expected `email` to be unique. Value: `test@test.com` } ]
```

But when it is sent to angular2, it is stored as a string

```
_body: "[{"error":"Error, expected `_id` to be unique. Value: `111111`"},{"error":"Error, expected `email` to be unique. Value: `test@test.com`"}]"
headers: ...
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "OK"
type: 2
url: ...
```

at the moment I am trying just logging 'err' to console in Angular2. But i've tried doing JSON.parse and i get this error:`EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`.

Also in express I have tried many different ways of sending the array i have tried `.json(errors);` instead of `.send(JSON.stringify(errors));`

Any ideas would be appreciated

**EDIT**
angular2 code:

```
err => console.log(err)
```

i have tried`JSON.parse(err)` and I have tried `private errors = [];` and insert 'err' into that array but nothing changes, i still gt the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

Try this stuff..

```
student.save(function(err, student) {
  if (err) {
    var errors = [];
    for (var field in err.errors) {
      errors.push({
        error: err.errors[field].message
      });
    }
    return res.contentType('application/json').status(500).send(errors);
  }
  res.status(200).json(student);
});
```

Comment: What you get when print `console.log(err)`?  and from where you get `err` value can you put angular code in your question?

Comment: `console.log(err)` in angular2 ??? that's the thing it produces this: `_body: "[{"error":"Error, expected `_id` to be unique. Value: `111111`"},{"error":"Error, expected `email` to be unique. Value: `test@test.com`"}]"
headers: ...
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "OK"
type: 2
url: ...` which mentioned on the main post, it stores all result into '_body' ??